# Only allow alphabetical characters at the beginning of a string?

Tags: python, regex

I want to grab the start of the first alphabetical characters at the beginning of the string:

```
||hello there -> hello there
((hello there -> hello there
```

I am using this code:

```
str = re.findall('^[^a-zA-Z]+(.*?)', str)
```

str gives me an array of two strings, the first string which is a blank string.

Comment: `str` is a builtin, it's really a bad idea to rebind it to something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
re.findall('^[^a-zA-Z]*(.*)', str)
```

Comment: Hello, I also want to get the whole rest of the string. I have edited the main body accordingly.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. I edited the regex, does it have the behavior you want now?

Comment: This will work for that. Try: `re.findall('^[^a-zA-Z]*(.*)', "))hello there")` ETA: Oh, I'm looking at the edited version I suppose. +1!

Answer (score 0):

To be unicode compatible, use `\pL` wich means a letter.

```
^\pL
```

This regex ensure you that you have at least one letter at the begining of the string.

If you want to capture the rest of the string:

```
^\pL(.*)$
```